# XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcCalculateNow) throws a XlCallException when evented from a backgroundworker

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I have an ExcelFunction that queues up some calculations:

```
[ExcelFunction(...)]
public static void QueueCalcs(... takes ranges ...)
{
    var calcRequests = ... builds list of calc request parameters from ranges ...
    calcRequests.ForEach(QueueCalculation);
}

public static void QueueCalculation(calcRequestParameters)
{
    var bWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    bWorker.DoWork += bWorkerDoWork;
    bWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += bWorkerRunWorkerCompleted;
    bWorker.RunWorkerAsnc(calcRequestParameters);
}

private static void bWorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcCalculateNow);
}
```

The worker completes successfully, but the OnComplete delegate throws:

```
Exception of type 'ExcelDna.Integration.XlCallException' was thrown
```

If I remove the background worker and use a regular foreach loop followed by a call to XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcCalculateNow), the function behaves as expected.

Is doing something like this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call the Excel C API (XlCall.Excel or any of the ExcelReference methods) from a non-calculation thread.

Excel-DNA has a helper to let you queue work to run in a macro context on the main Excel thread - call `ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro(...)`.

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to implement asynchronous functions, this doesn't seem like the right approach.... There is some built-in support for [one-time async functions](https://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Asynchronous%20Functions) or [real-time data feeds based on the Reactive Extensions](https://exceldna.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Reactive%20Extensions%20for%20Excel).

Comment: ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro(...) worked. I have spent the past few hours trying to use either a RDT server or the RxExtensions, but the lack of examples has been a deterrent to getting anything working. Basically, I want to query some webservices for calculations, cache the responses in the add-in, and provide access to properties of a cached response through excel functions. Is there a working example out there that could guide me along?

Comment: Maybe you can try this example: http://excel-dna.net/2013/04/02/caching-and-asynchronous-excel-udfs/ and then post to the Google group at http://groups.google.com/group/excedna with follow-up questions.

Comment: I feel a bit dumb for missing that post. Thanks, I will take a look.