# c#: ExcelDNA display an array in excel

Tags: arrays, excel-dna

I'm creating a plugin for excel, i would like to know how is it possible to create new rows to display a list or array

I created a sample function :

```
[ExcelFunction(Description = "Split string", Category = "STRING")]
    public static object[] StringSplit([ExcelArgument(Name = "TEXT", Description = "text to split")] string text)
    {
        return text.Split(' ').ToArray();
    }
```

In this example, the function returns an array with the different keywords. but when i use it via excel, it displays only the first word in my cell.
what i want to know is to create news columns or rows and display each element of my array in it.
thanks

**Edit**
I tried the solution posted by @C. Augusto Proiete bellow, so it works fine with this code :

```
Page page = new Page();
        WebResponse resp = page.Download(url);
        List<string> res = page.GetAllFromXpath(resp.content, xpath);
        object[,] result = new object[1, res.Count];

        for (int j = 0; j < res.Count; j++)
        {
            result[0, j] = res.ElementAt(j);
        }
       return Resizer.Resize(result);
```

but when i try the asyncrohous method, this throw an exeption not handled :

```
return ExcelAsyncUtil.Run("DownloadAsync", url,
           delegate
           {
               Page page = new Page();
               WebResponse resp = page.Download(url);
               List<string> res = page.GetAllFromXpath(resp.content, xpath);
               object[,] result = new object[1, res.Count];

               for (int j = 0; j < res.Count; j++)
               {
                   result[0, j] = res.ElementAt(j);
               }

               return Resizer.ResizeMe(result);
           });
```

the exception thrown is :

```
ExcelDna.Integration.XlCallException' occurred in ExcelDna.Integration.dll but was not handled in user code
```

And here is the line in the Reizer class that throw it:

```
ExcelReference caller = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfCaller) as ExcelReference;
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903055/xlcall-excelxlcall-xlccalculatenow-throws-a-xlcallexception-when-evented-from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering you're returning an array, you can span the results across columns by entering the formula in array mode.

Select the cells horizontally, type in the formula, and press `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`.

For example, selecting `A1:C1` and typing `=StringSplit("a b c")` as an array formula, will display the three elements of the array in the three cells selected.

[image]

You need to know upfront how many elements will be returned and select the correct number of cells appropriately.

If you don't know how many elements will be returned, then you might want to look at **[Resizing Excel UDF result arrays](https://excel-dna.net/2011/01/30/resizing-excel-udf-result-arrays/)**, but it's a hack and should be avoided if possible.

[Here is an example implementation](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/ArrayResizer.dna) of a helper macro that will resize your result array to the right size.

---

If you wanted to return rows and columns, you just need to return an `object[,]`

```
[ExcelFunction(Description = "Returns 2x2 matrix")]
public static object GetValues()
{
    return new object[,]
    {
        {1, 2},
        {3, 4},
    };
}
```

Everything else stays the same. You should return the number of elements that correspond to the number of cells selected by the user, unless you go with **[resizing result arrays](https://excel-dna.net/2011/01/30/resizing-excel-udf-result-arrays/) as per above.

Comment: humm, not really what i need, i'll check the hack but still think there is something native to do

Comment: @DanyM In that case, edit your question and try to express what you're looking for in a better way, including what you mean by "something native"

Comment: I don't know how many elements the string will return. i would like excel to create as many cells as needed

Comment: Excel does not allow you to modify the sheet from within a user-defined function. Doing this breaks Excel's calculation model. The resizing approach linked above would be the way to do what you're after, but as it says, it's a hack and should be avoided.

Comment: Instead of using a function/formula, consider creating a button on a Ribbon. That way you can access Excel's object model via COM, and do whatever you want...

Comment: what if i want to create new rows ? is it the same problem ?

Comment: It's the exact same thing... If the user selects 5 rows, you're expected to return 5 results for the 5 rows. If you need more, you'll have to resort to the resizing hack. See updated answer with an example returning a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: thanks @CaioProiete, your solution worked fine but only on sync mode. when i use ExcelAsyncUtil.Run, i get an exception from the Resizer Class : 
`code`
"An exception of type 'ExcelDna.Integration.XlCallException' occurred in ExcelDna.Integration.dll but was not handled in user code".
this occurs in the First line of the method Resize : 
`code`
ExcelReference caller = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfCaller) as ExcelReference; 
Do you have an idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: @DanyM `ExcelAsyncUtil.Run` executes code on a separate thread. You can only interact with Excel from the main thread of your add-in. Whenever you need to interact with Excel from a different thread, you need to use `ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro` https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/ArrayResizer.dna#L113

Comment: thanks @CaioProiet. do you have a simple code sample to show how to use QueueAsMacro ? i have edited the main post with my code, could you please reply to the post with an example ? thanks

Comment: @DanyM Look at line 113 of the ArrayResizer sample: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/ArrayResizer.dna#L113

Comment: i saw the line but still not know how to adapte my code, any help?