# Excel DNA attempting to write array from UDF only writes single value

Tags: excel-dna

I am attempting to write either an array function or a dynamic array to Excel via a UDF written in Excel DNA (v.0.34).  My result is always a single value instead of the array.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    [ExcelFunction(Name = "WriteTestArray")]
    public static object[,] WriteTestArray()
    {

        try
        {
            return new object[2, 2] { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" } };
        }
        catch
        {
            return new object[,] { { ExcelError.ExcelErrorValue } };
        }
    }
```

Comment: See this: [c#: ExcelDNA display an array in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305079/c-exceldna-display-an-array-in-excel/48306505)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For array functions to work with Excel (before the 'dynamic array' support that comes one day in a future version) you need to select the target range, then type in your formula and press Ctrl+Shift+Enter to commit it as an array formula. It will be indicated by curly brackets when displayed - e.g. `{=MyFunc(...)}`

Comment: so there is no way then to use a udf to insert say a table/array at an offset programatically?