# Excel Dna - How do I populate mutliple cells from the result of a UDF?

Tags: c#, excel-dna

I have the following function:

```
[ExcelFunction(Name = "GetFundPositions")]
public static object GetFundPositions()
{
    object[,] positions = new object[5, 2];

    positions[0, 0] = "BOOK_ABC"; positions[0, 1] = "USD";
    positions[1, 0] = "BOOK_ABC"; positions[1, 1] = "RUB";
    positions[2, 0] = "BOOK_DEF"; positions[2, 1] = "CHF";
    positions[3, 0] = "BOOK_XYZ"; positions[3, 1] = "EUR";
    positions[4, 0] = "BOOK_XYZ"; positions[4, 1] = "RUB";

    return XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlUDF, "Resize", positions);
}
```

Which I am calling in cell `A1` with the array formula:

```
{=GetFundPositions()}
```

I was expecting the results to be populated in cells `A1:B5` but only the first element of the array is being populated in cell `A1`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have the `Resize` function in your code... `Resize` is not a function that exists within Excel... It's the name of a function that should exist inside of your add-in (*and you can call it whatever you want... Doesn't have to be `Resize` BTW*).

That is the function responsible for doing all the work of resizing the range where the results appear.

You can see an example of the source code you need in the [ArrayResizer.dna](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/blob/master/Distribution/Samples/ArrayResizer.dna#L77-L81) sample code.

**However, this resizing technique has a number of known issues (e.g. [1](https://excel-dna.net/2011/01/30/resizing-excel-udf-result-arrays/), [2](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/203)) and should be avoided... [It's better to return the array without any resizing, and let the user select all the cells that should be filled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48306505/211672)**.

Comment: This is correct, but I want to point out that in Excel for Office 365 with the new calculation engine there is no need to pre-select the cells. The result will spill automatically. Further, if there is pre-existing content that is blocking the spill area, then the user will get a #SPILL! error.